# Is it possible to add a note with emacs buffers?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

While working on a project, or while browsing code I often open many buffers in emacs. There are often a lot of things that I am seeing in many windows. When the stack in my mind deepens I often forget what particular thing I was looking in some buffer/file which I opened 15-30 mins back. Is there a way where I can add a small note to these buffers when I open them, so I can always go back to them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [org mode's agenda feature](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html).

From within the currently open buffer, you can file away a note to review later.  You can set deadlines, TODO / WAITING labels, and most importantly, provide a hyperlink that will take you back to the exact location in the buffer you filed the note from.  And you can recall the list of stored links from anywhere with a simple keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using Org mode is to set Emacs *bookmarks* to keep track of places you have been and take notes about them.

You can add a note (an "annotation") to any bookmark when you create it (see option `bookmark-use-annotations`) or later (see `C-x r l`), and you can edit such annotations anytime.

With **[Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus)** you can even use [temporary](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc56) bookmarks, which don't get saved, and you can [tag](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc21) bookmarks with any number of tags you invent.

Both annotations and **Bookmark+** tags are free-form text.  You can search for the text in either annotations or tags across any set of bookmarks.  It is easy to organize bookmarks in various ways, including switching among different sets.